# What is required before an adjective that itself comes before a title: zero / indefinite / definite article?

Tags: articles

I was a bit puzzled by this sentence: 'But after Shrek met Donkey and lovely princess Fiona...'

So 'princess' here is a title of Fiona's. Furthermore, she is a 'lovely princess'.
Is it okay to leave this sentence with zero article?
Does 'and' change/influence anything?
What grammatical rule is this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I find it a bit odd. I would prefer _the lovely princess Fiona_.

Comment: Thank you, Colin! Any ideas as to what grammar this could be?

Comment: My guess that it is either the kind of grammar called a mistake, or the kind of grammar used by people who aren't native English speakers.

Comment: The sentence simplified is *Shrek met Donkey and Fiona*.

Comment: "Princess Fiona" is her full name including the title, like "Queen Elizabeth". It's acceptable to omit the article before the adjective "lovely".

Comment: That it would be better expressed as 'the lovely Princess…' does not make 'lovely Princess…' wrong.

Answer (score 1):

These two are correct:

> 1. But after Shrek met Donkey and lovely Princess Fiona...
> 2. But after Shrek met Donkey and the lovely princess Fiona

In (1), "Princess" is a title and incorporated into the name "Princess Fiona." In (2), "Fiona" is an appositive expression after "the lovely princess," which therefore needs a determiner.

But the version you provided, with no article and "princess" uncapitalized, is wrong:

> 3. * But after Shrek met Donkey and lovely princess Fiona,...